# ReactJs cards doesn`t work like in example

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When i running this code output must look like this(photo 1):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
but it look like this(photo 2)(i del images from source:https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/#image-overlays):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
i use webstorm if needed to know

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Navbar,Container,Nav,Card,CardDeck,CardGroup} from 'react-bootstrap';


function App() {
  return (
      <CardGroup>
        <Card>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>Card title</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>
              This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
              additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
            </Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
          <Card.Footer>
            <small className="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
          </Card.Footer>
        </Card>
        <Card>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>Card title</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>
              This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
              content.{' '}
            </Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
          <Card.Footer>
            <small className="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
          </Card.Footer>
        </Card>
        <Card>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>Card title</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>
              This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
              additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to
              show that equal height action.
            </Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
          <Card.Footer>
            <small className="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
          </Card.Footer>
        </Card>
      </CardGroup>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд вы не подключили стили Bootstrap!

Comment: На этом сайте принято писать по-русски